# cannot read type property of files inputed into form typescript angular

Tags: angular, file-upload, typeerror

I have a file form that I am uploading to.

```
samplemenuupload(event){
    let submittedpdfs = event.target.files;
    for(let pdf in submittedpdfs){
      console.log(submittedpdfs[+pdf]);
      if(submittedpdfs[+pdf].type !== acceptedpdf){
        submittedpdfs.splice(+pdf,1);
      }
    }
```

A file object looks like this. As you can see it has a `type` property

```
File(127001) {name: "2017-02-23-statements-1469.pdf", lastModified: 1492974543668, lastModifiedDate: Sun Apr 23 2017 14:09:03 GMT-0500 (CDT), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 127001, …}
lastModified:1492974543668
lastModifiedDate:Sun Apr 23 2017 14:09:03 GMT-0500 (CDT) {}
name:"2017-02-23-statements-1469.pdf"
size:127001
type:"application/pdf"
webkitRelativePath:""
```

when I go to check the type in the if statement I get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

whats going on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try assinging the object and then access,

```
let data = submittedpdfs[+pdf]);
if(data.type !== acceptedpdf)
```

Comment: Because it cannot evaluate the property on the same line. upvote answer if this helped